# How to highlight where a calcuation/value equals BETWEEN two prices/levels?

Tags: pine-script

I am looking for a quick solution in Pine Script where an alert is triggered where a series of conditions are met.

Upon further analysis, I noticed that more accurate signals occur where `outK3ref1` sits within the range from `70` to `80`

```
buy_alert1 = crossUpAll and (outK3ref1 = *******) and (stfcheckB<20) ? 1 : 0
```

None of the standard operators sound like they would give me the result I am after, I have tried a few combinations with no luck...

Comment: how about `(outK3ref1 >= 70 and outK3ref1 <=80)` ?

Comment: Yes - that works, thank you. I have 3 different buy alerts and was copying your suggestion with 'ref1' when I should have changed it to 'ref2' and 'ref'3 for the other alerts lol! Sorted now.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the `and` operator as well as greater-or-equal `>=` and lesser-or-equal `<=` enclosed in brackets to accomplish what you need.

```
buy_alert1 = crossUpAll and (outK3ref1 >= 70 and outK3ref1 <= 80) and (stfcheckB<20) ? 1 : 0
```

Also be careful, `=` is for assignment of value to a variable, `==` is for checking if two expressions are equal to each other.

```
a = 1 // assign 1 to a
a == 1 // returns true if a is equal to 1
```